# How to convert a dbf file to a dask dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, dbf

I have a big dbf file, converting it to a pandas dataframe is taking a lot of time.
Is there a way to convert the file into a dask dataframe?

Comment: Why is it taking so long? Dask will help in the case that the whole DB can't actually fit into memory but generally I've found it to be slower than pandas (when used on a single PC) in cases where the data _can_ fit into memory.

Comment: What is the size of the file?

Comment: What is dbf, please?

Comment: @roganjosh I have DBF files of 800-900 MB each. Most of the time is being consumed while converting it to the dataframe. Now, I have to perform the same operation for 1056 DBF files in total.

Comment: @Jondiedoop 1056 files for 800-900 MB

Comment: @mdurant A DBF file is a database file. Mine is generated through a database software called as FoxPro

Answer (score 0):

Dask does not have a dbf loading method.

As far as I can tell, dbf files do not support random-access to the data, so it is not possible to read from sections of the file in separate workers, in parallel. I may be wrong about this, but certainly dbfreader makes no mention of jumping through to an arbitrary record.

Therefore, the only way you could read from dbf in parallel, and hope to see a speed increase, would be to split your original data into multiple dbf files, and use `dask.delayed` to read each of them.

It is worth mentioning, that probably the reason dbfreader is slow (but please, do your own profiling!) is that it's doing byte-by-byte manipulations and making python objects for every record before passing the records to pandas. If you really wanted to speed things up, this code should be converted to cython or maybe numba, and a pre-allocated dataframe assigned into.

Comment: Hello @mdurant, Thanks for your suggestions . I will try converting the code.

Comment: Hi @mdurant, I have converted the DBF i to CSV and then converting it to a dataframe, I can observe a significant decrease in the time.